# Dynamic web content with java

Tags: java, web

I'm currently developing a Java project where I need to implement a Webserver. The webserver should be implemented because the installation should be easy. I already took a look at WebServlet and HttpServer from sun. As far as I know, it is always necessary to put the whole html into quotes in oder to use vars -e.g. collecting data from DB. What is the easiest way to use java code in html like php? (not js) Including the php module into the java server seems wrong to me. But when putting the whole document into vars, quotes are always necessary and it has no syntax highlights.

EDIT: I do not mean static content :)

Comment: Are you familiar with JSP?

Comment: Take a look at [Java servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) and [JavaServer Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages).

Comment: If I understood it correct, I need a separate webserver for java servlet. Is there anything similar to JSP for sun httpserver?